# Missing ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" as target framework in "New Project" window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, .net-client-profile

".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" is missing in the "New Project" window in Visual Studio 2010, so I cannot set it as a target framework.

[image: Missing Client Profile]

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use it, it is nothing but trouble.  It is only 15% smaller than the full version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal. You won't see in this combobox. Depending on the project type you are creating (windows, web, ...) Visual Studio will choose it. Once the project created you can go to the project properties and modify it there:

[image]